# What is the right way of accessing IPNS content?

Tags: ipfs, ipns

I want to access a file through its IPNS name (`/ipns/k51qzi5uqu5dlvj2baxnqndepeb86cbk3ng7n3i46uzyxzyqj2xjonzllnv0v8`).

As per [IPFS documentation](https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/ipns/#ipns-in-practice) I should be able to do this by using https://ipfs.io/ipns/k51qzi5uqu5dlvj2baxnqndepeb86cbk3ng7n3i46uzyxzyqj2xjonzllnv0v8

The problem I have is that I am getting a 504 Gateway Time-Out when I try to do it. Is there any other way of accessing content behind IPNS?